# Patch semantics

Tags: diff, semantics, patch

I've made a patch by using `diff`:

```
diff -u /home/user/onderzoeksstage/omf/Rakefile /home/user/onderzoeksstage/Rakefile > rakefile2.patch
```

I've placed this rakefile2.patch in another directory: `/home/user/onderzoeksstage/omf/confine/patches`.
Now, I was under the assumption that I could go to that directory where all my patches are collected, call `patch < rakefile2.patch` and `patch` would known where to find the file to patch (the original file `/home/user/onderzoeksstage/omf/Rakefile`) by reading out the rakefile2.patch header.

But when doing that, `patch` says that it does not find the file to patch:

```
[user@localhost patches]$ patch < rakefile2.patch 
can't find file to patch at input line 3
Perhaps you should have used the -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|--- /home/user/onderzoeksstage/omf/Rakefile    2013-02-12 14:11:49.809792527 +0100
|+++ /home/user/onderzoeksstage/Rakefile    2013-02-12 12:17:50.314831492 +0100
--------------------------
File to patch: ...
...
```

So my assumption was obviously wrong, but so how does `patch` work?
When going to `/home/user/onderzoeksstage/omf/` and calling `patch < rakefile2.patch` does work. Does `patch` only look at the header for the filename at the end of the path and not take in account the directory? And so what I try to accomplish will never work?
Why is this; is this because that way a patch could be applied to any file called Rakefile (e.g. in my case) and so make it a more "generic" patch?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Does patch only look at the header for the filename at the end of the
>   path and not take in account the directory?

That's what it does by default. See the description of `-p` option in [`man patch`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/patch). Looks like `-p0` is what you want here.

Comment: Yes, I thought the same and tried this (patch -p0 < rakefile2.patch) already before posting this question, but I got: patch: **** rejecting absolute target file name: /home/user/onderzoeksstage/Rakefile I got no idea why it got rejected, though.

Comment: It's probably for some kind of security/predictability. You can always `cd /` and use `patch -p1` (which will strip the leading slash and use the rest as "relative" path, and it will be the same as absolute path when `/` is your current directory).